# Building a form in Access can filter specific records in a table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Is it possible for an Access form to filter specific fields in the record source table so the user can deal with them only a part form the rest of the table fields?

The table contains many fields and the user needs to enter data in all fields for the different records in the table. To make it easy, I need to filter the records which have similar or are common in a specific character to enter their data, then remove the filter and put another filter for another character.

Answer (score 2):

Example solution:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

   Dim argsString As String, sFil As String

   argsString = Me.OpenArgs
   MsgBox "Incoming OpenArgs = " & argsString

   sFil = "SpecGrpID = " & argsString
   Me.Filter = sFil
   Me.FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Access provides record filtering features "out of the box". An Access form (or a table in Datasheet View) can be told to filter records interactively:

How to filter records in an Access database
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304259

...or programmatically:

Filter Property
http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/filter-property-HA001232736.aspx